# Basic jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing code for a very basic jQuery slider with the following features:

1. Slide the content left or right on click of next/previous links till there is no more content on the clicked side.
2. If any content is added dynamically, the entire content should slide.

While there are still many additions and modifications necessary, I would like to know if my approach is correct and the code that I am writing is going the correct way.

I am planning to write a plugin for this later.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gentrobot/RY3TH/2/)

```js
    $('#next').click(function(){
      //slide a div only if there is a next element
      if($('.currentRight').length >0)
      {        
        $('.current').animate({left:'-100px'}).removeClass('current').addClass('currentLeft').next().animate({left:'0px'}).removeClass('currentRight').addClass('current');
      }
    });
    
    $('#previous').click(function(){
      //slide a div only if there is a previous element  
      if($('.currentLeft').length >0)
      {
         $('.current').animate({left:'100px'}).removeClass('current').addClass('currentRight').prev().animate({left:'0px'}).removeClass('currentLeft').addClass('current');
      }
    });
    
    $('#add').click(function(){
      //it is used for simplicity's sake. I intend to use append()/prepend() to add more content
      var cont = $('.current').html()+'More<br/>';
      $('.current').html(cont);   
      var ht = $('.current').css('height');
      $('#container').css('height',ht);    
    });
```

```css
    /*the main div that contains all the sliding div*/
    #container{
        width:100px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        height:20px;
        position: relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    /*there are 3 different classes 
    * current - div that is presently visible
    * currentLeft - div that should slide from left on pressing previous
    * currentRight - div that should slide from right on pressing next
    */
    .current{
        width:99px;
        height:auto;
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        left:0px;
    }
    
    .currentLeft{
        width:99px;
        height:auto;
        position: absolute;
        left:-100px;
        float:left;
    }
    .currentRight{
        width:99px;
        height:auto;
        position: absolute;
        left:100px;
        float:left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
        <div class="currentLeft">
            First Div
        </div>
        <div class="current">
         Second Div
        </div>
        <div class="currentRight">
         Third Div
        </div>    
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="previous">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
    <a href="#" id="add">Add content</a>
    ​
```

Comment: On code review one is supposed to include at least part of one's code in the question.

Comment: The link for the fiddle has the entire code. I thought it would be easier to review the code at the fiddle since the jQuery, CSS and HTML are separated and also are working.

Comment: @Inkbug: Included the code. Thanks for improvement suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RY3TH/3/)

Not writing this as a plugin here are some suggestions:

1. instead of `removeClass('a').addClass('b')` use `toggleClass('a b')`
2. instead of searching the entire DOM for `.current` you should constrain it to the children of `#container`
3. instead of `css('height')` use `height()`
4. you should set the container height to the maximum height of all child elements, not just the height of the current visible one